# Open only one popup window (panel)

Tags: javascript, extjs

So i have this function onDisplayError which is called each time if request fails. This means if user press save button and 3 request are failing i currently getting 3 popup messages. My goal is that this function checks if my popup window is already opened. If it is then i will append errors in my already opened window otherwise it should open this error popup

```
onDisplayError: function (response, message) {
        var errorPanel = Ext.create('myApp.view.popup.error.Panel',{
            shortMessage: message,
            trace: response
        });
        if(errorPanel.rendered == true){
            console.log('Do some other stuff');
        }else{
            errorPanel.show();
        }
    },
```

This is Panel.js

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.popup.error.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
        'myApp.view.popup.error.PanelController'
    ],
    controller: 'myApp_view_popup_error_PanelController',

    title: 'Fail',
    glyph: 'xf071@FontAwesome',

    floating: true,
    draggable: true,
    modal: true,
    closable: true,
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    layout: 'border',
    shortMessage: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 200,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            this.getMessagePanel(),
            this.getDetailsPanel()
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    getMessagePanel: function() {
        if(!this.messagePanel) {
            var message = this.shortMessage;
            this.messagePanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                bodyPadding: 5,
                height: 200,
                region: 'center',
                border: false,
                html: message
            });
        }
        return this.messagePanel;
    },

    getDetailsPanel: function() {
        if(!this.detailsPanel) {
            this.detailsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                title: 'Details',
                hidden: true,
                region: 'south',
                scrollable: true,
                bodyPadding: 5,
                height: 400,
                html: '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(this.trace, null, 4) + '</pre>'
            });
        }
        return this.detailsPanel;
    }
```

The problem is that i'm still getting multiple popups displayed. I think that the problem is that var errorPanel loses reference so it can't check if this popup (panel) is already opened. How to achieve desired effect? I'm working with extjs 6. If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide to your component definition a special `xtype`.

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.popup.error.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype:'myxtype'
```

and then you could have a very condensed `onDisplayError` function:

```
onDisplayError: function (response, message) {
    var errorPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('myxtype')[0] || Ext.widget('myxtype');
    errorPanel.appendError(message, response)
    errorPanel.show();
},
```

The panel's `initComponent` function should initialize an empty window, and `appendError` should contain your logic to append an error (which may be the first error as well as the second or the third) to the list of errors in the panel.

Comment: great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using Ext.create will always create a new instance of that class.

You can use the reference config to create a unique reference to the panel.
Then, use this.lookupReference('referenceName') in the controller to check if the panel already exists, and show().

You also have to set closeAction: 'hide' in the panel, to avoid panel destruction on close.

Otherwise, you can save a reference to the panel in the controller

this.errorPanel = Ext.create('myApp.view.popup.error.Panel' ....

Then, if (this.errorPanel) this.errorPanel.show();
else this.errorPanel = Ext.create...